# contactPoint for organizations (schema.org)

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, knowledge-graph

https://developers.google.com/structured-data/customize/contact-points
describes how to "use corporate contact markup on your official website to add your company's contact information to the Google Knowledge panel in some searches".

I'm wondering if one should put only one JSON-markup on the homepage containing the organizations phone numbers e.g. for customer service and sales or if it is possible to have several of them on different subpages.

For example on www.mywebsite.com/ I would include

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "http://www.mywebsite.com",
  "contactPoint" : [{
    "@type" : "ContactPoint",
    "telephone" : "+1-877-746-0909",
    "contactType" : "customer service",
  }
</script>
```

for the general customer service.

On the site www.mywebsite.com/productA

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context" : "http://schema.org",
  "@type" : "Organization",
  "url" : "http://http://www.mywebsite.com/productA",
  "contactPoint" : [{
    "@type" : "ContactPoint",
    "telephone" : "+1-877-746-0919",
    "contactType" : "customer service",
  }
</script>
```

for the customer service of a special product.

And on the site www.mywebsite.com/productB i put JSON-markup for the customer service of another product.

Or is an organization supposed to have only one occuring contactPoint per contactType for the entire website (including subpages)?

How would this affect the "Google Knowledge panel"? Is this panel always the same for the entire website oder does it vary depending on the url of the searchresult?

The organization has about 600 contacts. Does it make any sense to create JSON-markup for each of them on various pages, if they don't have one of the organizations contactTypes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `url` value of `Organization` should be the organization’s page (typically the homepage of the organization’s website), not (also) the pages of the organization’s products.

This is also the case for Google’s own guidelines for their Corporate Contacts feature (bold emphasis mine):

> - Include an Organization record in your markup that includes both:
>
>   - Your organization's **official URL**
>   - […]

So you could provide several `ContactPoint` items, but this shouldn’t change the `url` of your `Organization`.

And from the perspective of Schema.org it’s fine to provide these `ContactPoint` items on different pages of your site, but I don’t know if Google support this for their Corporate Contacts feature (their documentation assumes the common case of having only one page with this markup).